# How to remove special character in Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to send the image to View through by Ajax.

But in Admin page with PHP I add multiple images. So, list image will have format like:

`["image_1.jpg","image_2.jpg","image_3.jpg"]`

I want to show list image in `div#res`.
It does not remove character like: `[" "," "]`.

Here my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.thang').click(function(){
        var id_thang = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl+'/Home/getImage',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id_thang: id_thang},
        }).done(function(result) {
            var image_list = result.image_list;
            for(m = 0; m < image_list.length; m++){
                '<img data-u="image" src="img/product/' + image_list[m]+ ' alt="" />'  + '</br>';
            }
           $('#res').html(image_list);
        })
    });
});
```

It becomes to:

```
<img data-u="image" src="img/product/["image_1.jpg","image_2.jpg","image_3.jpg"] alt="" />
```

I only need like this:

```
<img data-u="image" src="img/product/image_1.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-u="image" src="img/product/image_2.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-u="image" src="img/product/image_3.jpg" alt="" />
```

**Updated 1 with more information:**

I have function to get image by id:

```
function getImage(){
    $id_thang = $this->input->post('id_thang');
    $input = array();
    $input['order'] = array('id','ASC');
    $get_image_thang  = $this->Mmenushoatnao->get_info($id_thang);
    echo json_encode($get_image_thang);
}
```

And here my full code in Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.thang').click(function(){
        var id_thang = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl+'/Home/getImage',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id_thang: id_thang},
        }).done(function(result) {
            // console.log(result);
            var image_list = result.image_list;
            for(m = 0; m < image_list.length; m++){
                image_list += '<img data-u="image" src="upload/hoatnao/hinhanh/' + result.image_list[m]+ ' alt="" />'  + '</br>';
                console.log(image_list);
            }
           $('#res').html(image_list);  
        })      
    });
});
```

Finally, I print it with `id=res`:

```
<div id="res" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">

</div>
```

And here is an image.

Each row has about four an image.

You can see in my database.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `concatenation`

```
var image_list = "";
for(m = 0; m < result.image_list.length; m++){
    image_list += '<img data-u="image" src="img/product/' + result.image_list[m]+ ' alt="" />'  + '</br>';
}
$('#res').html(image_list);
```

FYI, do `console.log` to make sure that you're getting proper data as per your need and I shown you a way to achieve that but make sure that you're using proper variable names.

Comment: I tried your answer, my browser is stop working. Seem it loop forever, I must turn off computer. I capture in console like this: http://i.imgur.com/HvYwrcY.png

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle or update your question to understand your code, and what you're getting in result, please show me that.?

I already mentioned that don't forget to use proper variable names as per your result.

Comment: When I console.log(result.image_list[m]) it show result like: `["image_1.jpg","image_2.jpg","image_3.jpg"]`. I think it not remove special character. Because in imgur image, it don't have values: undefine.

Comment: How many images you're getting ? And update your question with full code and response.. `console.log(result);` what this giving ?

Comment: See my for loop and your ? there is difference `image_list.length` and `result.image_list.length`

Comment: I think it fail at the loop. I debug, and it shows values of `image_list` like: `[` > `"` > `i` > `m` >  `a`,.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125572/discussion-between-loading-and-vn-lc).